# How to get value of encrypted data bag secret within Test Kitchen

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have added `data_bags_path` and `encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path` within `kitchen.yml` as follows:

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  chef_omnibus_url: omni-url/chef/install.sh
  roles_path: 'test/integration/default/roles'
  data_bags_path: "test/integration/default/data_bags"
  encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path: "test/integration/default/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
```

I believe the above copies the `encrypted_data_bag_secret` to a file named encrypted_data_bag_secret under `/tmp/kitchen/`

That is why, in my recipe I am calling secret as follows:

```
secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/tmp/kitchen/encrypted_data_bag_secret")
encryptkey = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("tokens", "encryptkey", secret)
```

However, the test kitchen is failing with following error:

`No such file or directory - file not found '/tmp/kitchen/encrypted_data_bag_secret'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you probably don't want to use encrypted data bags in your tests. If you do want to use the encryption for some reason (really, don't) use the normal `data_bag_item()` API which does the key loading for you.

Comment: thanks. I am able to make it work using `encryptkey = data_bag_item("tokens", "encryptkey")`

Comment: can you please suggest why encrypted data bags should not be used in test kitchen?

Comment: Because the point is to test your code, not test that Chef works correctly.